# Jenkins docker load permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to load a tar ball using docker load in Jenkins pipeline. I am getting below error

```
+ docker load -i /home/test/build_artifacts/test.tar
open /home/test/build_artifacts/test.tar: permission denied
```

Here is my docker pipeline script

```
docker.withRegistry(registry, credentials) {
      sh "docker load -i /home/test/build_artifacts/${repo_name}.tar"
      docker.image(repo_name).push('latest')
}
```

I have already tried below and restarted my jenkins!

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

and

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker root
```

Further docker load on terminal runs perfectly fine, so it must something related to jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in the fact that docker save always creates a tarball with restricted permissions, we need to do a `chmod 755` immediately after saving the file in the source machine then docker load in the destination works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

When you use terminal, you are authenticated as your local user who probably has the necessary permissions. When you run a Jenkins pipeline, the pipeline runs as the `jenkins` user who is likely missing the necessary permissions. You either need to use `chmod` to give the permissions, or have the artifacts get created and retrieved from within the `jenkins` users' home directory.

Comment: Thanks but chmod is part of the answer I realized docker save creates tarball with restricted permissions so chmod after save is a must